# Angular 8 Cancel or do something before navigation starts

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a scenario where I have a route

`<a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>`

in the controller I would like to cancel the rout navigation based on a value.

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
 cancelRoute : boolean = true

  constructor(
   //some logic where before the route is navigated to, I want it to cancel the route
   // and log a message to console
   //console.log('successfully, canceled route');
  ) {}
```

***EDIT***

I do not want this done through a Route Guard, i want this done at the component level. I have a component on the page, that I want to cancel route navigation.

here is my use case.

I have a page which hosts multiple components, If someone leaves the page I want to check with component A and make sure there isnt any unsaved data before they navigate away.

***EDIT 2***

> "I do not want this done through a Route Guard". Why? This is essentially what the CanDeactivate guard exists for. You can definitely use it for your use case with ease.

Correct me If I am wrong, but I would need to put the CanDeactivateGuard On every route for example

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'team/:id',
    component: TeamComponent,
    canDeactivate: ['canDeactivateTeam']
  }
```

I do not want to have a CanDeactivate on every route, when Only 1 route
have `foo` component inside.

There are many routes, only one route needs `foo` component and he need to can cancel the route navigation. As far as I know the `canDeactivate` route gaurd cannot access components created on a route.

***EDIT 3***

[NavigationStart](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart) The docs state that this is an event that is fired. I can hook into that event, but I cannot stop the actually navigation. Unless I am wrong `NavigatonStart` just tells me when it starts navigating not how to stop the navigation.

Comment: This is done *outside* of the component. You are looking for a Route Guard.

Comment: How about using `NavigationStart` of Router event?

Comment: Also I think you mean to write component instead of controller.

Comment: See also https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication as an example of how to do this.

Comment: "I do not want this done through a Route Guard". Why? This is essentially what the ```CanDeactivate``` guard exists for. You can definitely use it for your use case with ease.

Comment: @nullptr.t I updated my question to answer your comment.

Comment: @MaihanNijat Yeah he need NavigationStart XD

Comment: @MaihanNijat No At the end You are wrong !!! He needs canDeactivate. XD

Comment: You put canDeactivate on the route you leave, not the one you navigate to. And since that unsaved data is on the component you want to leave, can deactivate fits there perfectly.

Comment: Where is 
this line located:
<a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>, is it in the HeroListComponent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no other way to prevent from navigate with no DeactivateGuard, but! You can make him as injectable.

```
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<HomeComponent> {

    canDeact = true

  canDeactivate() {
    return this.canDeact
  }
}
```

You can inject it to any component You want and change `canDeact` to false so You prevent from navigate to other route when job is not done. Still, on default `canDeact` is true, so if in your route there will be no component `foo` with will trigger ngOnInit which make guard false and prevent from navigate out.

so guard as above and setup canDeactivate in routing:

```
{
    path: 'team/:id',
    component: TeamComponent,
    canDeactivate: [DeactivateGuard]
}
```

Becouse of it is injectable provide it in some root module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    DeactivateGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Assuming, some times foo component will be inside TeamComponent. Just in foo component:

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private deactGuard: DeactivateGuard) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deactGuard.canDeact = false
  }

  jobDone() {
    this.deactGuard.canDeact = true
  }

}
```

Try to not paste foo component outside of TeamComponent range. Or develop it correct in ngOnInit so he will not make canDeact false when ever he want's to.

Comment: This seems like a good answer to my needs. Can you show me what the route would look like and How I would wire this up? If not thats cool too and i can try and figure it out

Comment: @gh9 Yeah i can.

Comment: Sweet, thanks very much! You sir deserve more up votes hopefully this question will generate more for you.

Comment: @gh9 Updated. Don't think Will generate more.

Comment: No worries i can make it work from here, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Edit based on the comment below:
One possible solution would be the following:
Change X.component.html to:

```
<a (click)='goToCrisisCenter()' routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>
```

X.component.ts

```
constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {}

goToCrisisCenter() {
  this.navigationService.tryNavigateTo('/crisis-center');
}
```

Create NavigationService with:

```
canNavigate = true;
tryNavigateTo(route:string) {
  if(canNavigate) this.router.navigate([/crisis-center])
}
```

Inject NavigationService in HeroListComponent and manipulate canNavigate as it suits you.

Comment: The route isnt on the component its on another component, if it were on the same component you would 100% be accurate.

Comment: @gh9 I've re-written my answer to cover this.

Comment: @SimonKazakov He will need to change whole navigation system = no more use `routerLink=""` any where.

Comment: In AppModule.ts `providers: [{ provide: Router, useClass: CrisisCenter,}]` lol. XD

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
 cancelRoute : boolean = true

  constructor(provate router: Router) {
   if (cancelRoute) {
     this.router.navigate(["/yourRoute"]);
   } else {
     this.router.navigate(["/yourRouteElse"]); 
   }
}
// If you don't want me to do something the `else`, leave it empty.
```

I leave you a documentation:
https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-routerlink-navigate-navigatebyurl/

Comment: That doesn't cancel a route, that just navigates somewhere else. And please post answers in English since SO is an English only site.

Comment: Here is the link to the SO Spanish site. https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Please wrote in English language Mr. Gómez.